# the estimate for sum of the falling powers of a factorial

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Define the sum of the falling powers of a factorial to be $1^{n!} + 2^{n!-1} + 3^{n!-2} + ..+ n!^1$.  For $n=3$ we have $1^6 + 2^5 + 3^4 + 4^3 + 5^2 + 6^1=209 There is no need to wait for much larger sums to appear.  Do you think there is an accurate estimate for increasing factorials n!?  They are not as large as my from yesterday product of falling powers of a factorial but still rather bulky.

Comment: What's that "209"??? How did you get from $3^4$ to $5^2$? What do you mean by "There is no need to wait for much larger sums to appear"??? No offense, but your question needs some serious rephrasing IMO.

Comment: I just fixed some of the content, but I left some parts of it as the OP has written them, although I seriously doubt that there should be $209$ over there.

Comment: I agree and I just did it.  The first time was at the library during story time for children=NOISE and typos.  Look at the sum for 4! to get 1^24 + 2^23+3^23+...24^1 and you'll see what I mean by rapidly growing sums. They are not as large as yesterday's product of falling powers of factorial but still hefty.

Comment: What are these references to this yesterday stuff of yours? Are we supposed to know your question history?

Comment: If we can have a product, we can have a sum.  I just mentioned the product of falling powers of a factorial for comparison sake.  Anyway, how long would it take to enter "product of falling powers of a factorial"?

Comment: "my from yesterday product": very sorry, I am not focused on your daily activity.

Comment: Is there any benefit of restricting to factorials ? I guess that $\sum_{k=1}^n k^{n-k+1}$ is more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

As a very crude approximation of $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nk^{n+1-k},$$ you can estimate the sum as the area under the curve

$$y=x^{n+1-x}$$

itself given by the product of the peak height by the peak width.

The width can be taken at $y=1$, giving $x=1$ and $x=n+1$.

The height is harder to get as is corresponds to the zero of the derivative, giving

$$-\ln x+\frac{n+1}x-1=0,$$

or $$ex\ln ex=e(n+1)$$ and
$$ex=W(\exp(e(n+1))).$$

Hence

$$x\approx\frac1eW(\exp(e(n+1)))$$

and using the asymptotic development of $W$,

$$x\approx (n+1)-\frac 1e\ln e(n+1).$$

Then

$$S_n\approx n\left((n+1)-\frac 1e\ln e(n+1)\right)^{\frac 1e\ln e(n+1)}.$$

Comment: Would testing the approximation give values lower or higher than the actual sum if patiently, arduously, exactly calculated?  I didn't restrict it  to factorials but extended the forbidden and immoral work done on the falling product of a factorial.

Comment: @J.M.Bergot: $S_1=1,S_2=3,\cdots$. The rest is left as an exercise.